# snprintf overflows and prints garbage to file randomly. help

Tags: c, programming-languages, printf

Here is my code, basically one the 4 computer I have tested it on they all work perfectly with very large data sizes, eg textfiles up to 500mb in size, but when I run them on the server with real data even files as small as 6mb seem to overrun somewhere and writes garbage to the end of my files.

Here is the source of the entire function so people can have a more indepth look

```
/** Reads values from tagname between start_time and end_time which are strings in the format 
 of 01/01/1970-12:00, a null string is treated as 01/01/1970, values are stored in
 "tagname".csv */
int ReadValues(char * tagname, char * start_time, char * end_time, char * working_directory, char * new_tag_name)
{
 long lRet;
 int  number_of_samples;
 int     loop;
 IHU_DATA_SAMPLE  * pSamples=NULL;
 IHU_TIMESTAMP  StartTime;
 IHU_TIMESTAMP  EndTime;
 FILE *stream;
 char outputFileName[200];
 char szQuality[100];
 char    newTempTagName[100];
 int  Year;
 int  Month;
 int  Day;
 int  Hour;
 int  Minute;
 int  Second;
 long Subsecond;
 int date[10];

    //if we want to change the tagname do it now
 if(new_tag_name != 0){
       strncpy(newTempTagName, new_tag_name, 100);
    } else {
       strncpy(newTempTagName, tagname, 100);  
    } 

 // if the tagname contains a character that is invalid for a filename then we have to make a name
 if ( (strstr(newTempTagName, "/")) || (strstr(newTempTagName, "\\")) || (strstr(newTempTagName, ":")))
 {

  sprintf(outputFileName, "MadeUpTag%d", MadeUpTagCount++);
 }
 else
 {

        //If a working directory was passed in use it
        if(!working_directory){           
            strncpy(outputFileName, newTempTagName,199);   
            } else {
      strcpy(outputFileName, working_directory); //Copy the working directory to the filename
      // Append a / on the end of the working directory if it doesn't already have one
         if(outputFileName[strlen(outputFileName)-1] == '\"'){                   
                outputFileName[strlen(outputFileName)-1] = 0;
            } 
            if(outputFileName[strlen(outputFileName)-1] != '\\'){         
                strncat(outputFileName, "\\", 199);                                
            }
            strncat(outputFileName, newTempTagName, 199);   //Copy the tagname to the end of the working directory
        }

 }

 //Add the csv file extension
 strcat(outputFileName, ".csv");
 #ifdef DEBUG
 printf("Output filename: %s\n", outputFileName);
 #endif

 stream = fopen(outputFileName, "w");
 if( stream == NULL ) {
  printf("The file %s can not be opened\n", outputFileName );
 } else {

  //If start_time == 0 we want to start at 1970
  if(start_time == 0){
   // we want all the data so use an old start time
   struct tm local;
   local.tm_year = date[2] - 1900;
   local.tm_mon = date[1] - 1;
   local.tm_mday = date[0];
   local.tm_hour = date[3];
   local.tm_min = date[4];
   local.tm_sec = 0;
            time_t utc_seconds = mktime(&local);
   StartTime.Seconds = (long)utc_seconds;
            StartTime.Subseconds = 0; 

  } else {
            //we have been supplied a start time
   #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("Start Time: ");
   #endif
            lRet = convert_date(start_time, &StartTime);
   #ifdef DEBUG

   printf("Seconds %ld \n", StartTime.Seconds);
   #endif
  }

  //if end_time == 0 we want to go all the way until now.
  if(end_time == 0){
   // end time of 0 means now
   memset(&EndTime, 0, sizeof(EndTime));
  } else {
            //we have been supplied an end time
   #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("End Time: ");
   #endif
            lRet = convert_date(end_time, &EndTime);
   #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("Seconds %ld \n", EndTime.Seconds);
   #endif
  }

  // API will determine actual samples that are in that time range
  number_of_samples=0;

  // API will allocate the memory
  pSamples = NULL;
     //timeTaken();
  lRet = ihuReadRawDataByTime
  (
   serverhandle,  // the handle returned from the connect
   tagname,   // the single tagname to retrieve 
   &StartTime,   // start time for query
   &EndTime,   // end time for query
   &number_of_samples, // will be set by API
   &pSamples   // will be allocated and populated in the user API
  );

        char temp[100];
        char Header[100];
        char lengthOfHeader = 0;
        char SampleAndTag[100];
        int  lengthOfSampleAndTag = 0;
        char ActualSample[100];
        int  lengthOfActualSample = 0;
        char NumberOfSamples[100];
        int  lengthOfNumberOfSamples = 0;
  int  oldQualityStatus = 99999;

  if (lRet == ihuSTATUS_OK)
  { 

      // successful read
            lengthOfHeader = snprintf(Header, 100, "[Data]\nTagname,TimeStamp,Value,DataQuality\n");
            if(lengthOfHeader < 0){
                printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n");                                 
            } else {
                if(fwrite(Header, 1, lengthOfHeader, stream) < lengthOfHeader){
                        printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE!\n");
                }
            }

   for (loop = 0;loop < number_of_samples;loop++)
   {
                struct tm * local;
                local = localtime(&pSamples[loop].TimeStamp.Seconds);
                Month = local->tm_mon + 1;
                Day = local->tm_mday;
                Year = local->tm_year + 1900;
                Hour = local->tm_hour;
                Minute = local->tm_min;
                Second = local->tm_sec;
                Subsecond = pSamples[loop].TimeStamp.Subseconds;

                //lengthOfSampleAndTag = snprintf(SampleAndTag, 100, "Sample %d, %s",loop, newTempTagName);
                lengthOfSampleAndTag = snprintf(SampleAndTag, 100, "%s", newTempTagName);
                if(lengthOfSampleAndTag < 0){
                   printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n");                                 
                } else {
                    if(fwrite(SampleAndTag, 1,lengthOfSampleAndTag, stream) < lengthOfSampleAndTag){
                        printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE!\n");
                    }
                }

                //Doing the formatting ourselves manually per character saves about 20% of cpu time
                //on large databases this can save hours
                temp[0] = ',';
    temp[1] = ' ';
    temp[2] = Month/10 + 0x30; //Tens
    temp[3] = Month%10 + 0x30; //units
    temp[4] = '/';
    temp[5] = Day/10 + 0x30;
    temp[6] = Day%10 + 0x30;
    temp[7] = '/';
    temp[8] = Year/1000 + 0x30;
    temp[9] = '0';
    temp[10] = (Year%100)/10 + 0x30;
    temp[11] = (Year%100)%10 + 0x30;
    temp[12] = ' ';
    temp[13] = Hour/10 + 0x30; //Tens
    temp[14] = Hour%10 + 0x30; //units
    temp[15] = ':';
    temp[16] = Minute/10 + 0x30;
    temp[17] = Minute%10 + 0x30;
    temp[18] = ':';
    temp[19] = Second/10 + 0x30;
    temp[20] = Second%10 + 0x30;
    temp[21] = '.';
    temp[22] = '0';
    temp[23] = '0';
    temp[24] = '0';
    temp[25] = ',';
    temp[26] = ' ';
    temp[27] = 0;  //Null termination

                //This is to save copying the string if it is the same
                if(oldQualityStatus != pSamples[loop].Quality.QualityStatus){
                    oldQualityStatus = pSamples[loop].Quality.QualityStatus;
        switch(pSamples[loop].Quality.QualityStatus)
        {
         case ihuOPCBad:
          strncpy(szQuality,"Bad",99);
          break;
         case ihuOPCUncertain:
          strncpy(szQuality,"Uncertain",99);
          break;
         case ihuOPCNA:
          strncpy(szQuality,"NotAvailable",99);
          break;
         case ihuOPCGood:
          strncpy(szQuality,"Good",99);
          break;
         default:
          strncpy(szQuality,"Really unknown",99);
          break;
        }
                }

    if ( pSamples[loop].ValueDataType == ihuFloat )
    {
                    //lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%8.7f, %s, Type:Float\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.Float,szQuality);
                    lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%8.7f, %s\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.Float,szQuality);
                    if(lengthOfActualSample < 0){
                         printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n");  
                    } else {
                        if(fwrite(ActualSample, 1, lengthOfActualSample, stream) < lengthOfActualSample){
                            printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE!\n");
                        }
                    }
    }
    else if ( pSamples[loop].ValueDataType == ihuDoubleFloat )
    {
                    //lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%8.15f, %s, Type: DoubleFloat\n ",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.DoubleFloat,szQuality);
                    lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%8.15f, %s\n ",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.DoubleFloat,szQuality);
                    if(lengthOfActualSample < 0){
                         printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n");   
                    } else {
                        if(fwrite(ActualSample, 1,lengthOfActualSample, stream) < lengthOfActualSample){
                            printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE!\n");
                        }
                    }

    }
    else if ( pSamples[loop].ValueDataType == ihuShort )
    {
                    //lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%d, %s, Type:Short\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.Short,szQuality);
                    lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%d, %s\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.Short,szQuality);
                    if(lengthOfActualSample <0){
                         printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n"); 
                    } else {
                        if(fwrite(ActualSample, 1, lengthOfActualSample, stream) < lengthOfActualSample){
                            printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE!\n");
                        }
                    }
    }
    else if ( pSamples[loop].ValueDataType == ihuInteger )
    {
                    //lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%d, %s, Type:Integer\n",temp, pSamples[loop].Value.Integer, szQuality);
                    lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%d, %s\n",temp, pSamples[loop].Value.Integer, szQuality);
                    if(lengthOfActualSample < 0){
                         printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n");  
                    } else {
                        if(fwrite(ActualSample, 1, lengthOfActualSample, stream) < lengthOfActualSample){
                            printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE! \n");
                        }
                    }

    }
    else if ( pSamples[loop].ValueDataType == ihuString )
    {
     //lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%s, %s, Type:String\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.String,szQuality);
                    lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%s, %s\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.String,szQuality);
                    if(lengthOfActualSample < 0){
                        printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n"); 
                    } else {
                        if(fwrite(ActualSample, 1, lengthOfActualSample, stream) < lengthOfActualSample){
                            printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE! \n");
                        }
                    }
    }     
   }
  }
  lengthOfNumberOfSamples = snprintf(NumberOfSamples, 100,"Number of samples: %d\n",number_of_samples);
  if(lengthOfNumberOfSamples < 0){
            printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n"); 
        } else {
            if(fwrite(NumberOfSamples, 1, lengthOfNumberOfSamples, stream) < lengthOfNumberOfSamples){
                printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE!\n");
            }
        }

      //timeDifference = GetTickCount() - timeDifference;
     //fprintf(stream, "Time taken: %d\n", timeDifference);
  // success or not you should free this
  FreeSamples(pSamples, number_of_samples);
  ihuFreePtr (pSamples);
  pSamples = NULL;
        timeTaken();
  fclose(stream);
 }


 return 0;
}
```

Here is a cut down version of the function so you don't have tor ead the entire source, however if you want to it is here. Ive optimised the code by manually formatting the string (temp[]) which runs about 40x faster but it is definitely null terminated so this shouldn't be an issue.

```
   stream = fopen(outputFileName, "w");

   for(...){
     ... lots of conditions
     if ( pSamples[loop].ValueDataType == ihuFloat )
     {
          lengthOfActualSample = snprintf(ActualSample, 100,"%s%8.7f, %s\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.Float,szQuality);
          if(lengthOfActualSample < 0){
               printf("ERROR WRITING TO BUFFER!\n");  
          } else {
               if(fwrite(ActualSample, 1, lengthOfActualSample, stream) < lengthOfActualSample){
                    printf("ERROR WRITING TO FILE!\n");
               }
          }
      }
    }

    fclose(stream);
```

Now the results:

```
Sample 81035, debug, 09/13/2010 11:10:55.000, 0.8900000, Good, Type:Float
Sample 81036, debug, 09/13/2010 11:11:00.000, 0.9500000, Good, Type:Float
Number of samples: 81037
**:56:15.000, 0.2800000, Good, Type:Float
Sample 80164, debug, 07/22/2010 15:56:20.000, 0.3400000, Good, Type:Float
Sample 80165, debug, 07/22/2010 15:56:30.000, 0.4100000, Good, Type:Float
... lots more samples
Sample 80322, debug, 08/01/2010 00:04:35.000, 0.5800000, Good, Type:Float
Sample 80323, debug, 08/01/2010 00:04:45.000, 0.6700000, Good, Type:Float
Sample 80324**
file ends here halfway through sample 80324
```

In bold you can see where the file is overruning and continuing to print garbage to the file after the final call to print("number of samples: ....)

The results SHOULD be this and ARE on every single computer I've tried it on (4) except the server which is the only PC it has to work on.

```
Sample 81035, debug, 09/13/2010 11:10:55.000, 0.8900000, Good, Type:Float
Sample 81036, debug, 09/13/2010 11:11:00.000, 0.9500000, Good, Type:Float
Number of samples: 81037
```

I am desperate to figure this out and have absolutely no idea why this is happening, does anyone have any ideas?

edit: I have these options on gcc -Wall -Wformat and I have ZERO warnings in my entire project. I have also compiled with -pedantic and

edit2: did a much smaller run and instead of overrunning with data it overruns with 0s or NUL

```
run1, 02/01/2010 08:50:50.000, 0.6000000, Good
run1, 02/01/2010 08:51:00.000, 0.6900000, Good
run1, 02/01/2010 08:51:10.000, 0.7600000, Good   #Sample505
Number of samples: 505
NULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNUL (0 in a hex editor)
```

As soon as the runs get bigger than around 1000 it starts printing garbage again though

```
run2, 03/31/2010 15:25:30.000, 0.8200000, Good
Number of samples: 1742
/22/2010 09:39:35.000, 0.5400000, Good
run2, 01/22/2010 09:39:45.000, 0.6400000, Good
run2, 01/22/2010 09:39:50.000, 0.6900000, Good
```

For some reason 2 runs worked consistently with sample size of 76660

```
run5, 12/31/2009 16:03:15.000, 0.6600000, Good
run5, 12/31/2009 16:03:25.000, 0.7600000, Good
Number of samples: 76660
```

So results conclude that <1000 prints nuls to the end of the file, between 1000 and 76660 it prints garbage and then at sample size 80234 also prints garbage at the end of the file, very odd but the excess data is always consistent and the same if run multiple times.

Comment: The surplus data looks like it's leftover from a previous or parallel run. Are multiple instances of this running on the server? Could conceivably be a reentrancy issue? (Btw, your printf error messages have wrongly-oriented slashes.)

Comment: see my new comment below, but yes they are different runs but with identical issues (surplus data) and there are no parallel runs, only a single program executing at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and I have solved my own problem!

I changed the code from this:

```
FreeSamples(pSamples, number_of_samples);
ihuFreePtr (pSamples);
pSamples = NULL;
timeTaken();
fclose(stream);
```

To this:

```
fclose(stream);
FreeSamples(pSamples, number_of_samples);
ihuFreePtr (pSamples);
pSamples = NULL;
timeTaken();
```

For some reason the user API I was using was corrupting my file when it was freeing the memory, I have absolutely no idea how or why, but it was.

Answer (score 6):

The following line uses an invalid `fprintf` format string:

```
fprintf(stream,"%s%8.15, %s, Type: DoubleFloat\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.DoubleFloat,szQuality)
```

Specifically, the `%8.15,` part.  You left out the type specifier.  If you are using gcc, you can use the `-Wformat` option to have the compiler check your `*printf` calls for errors like this.

Also, I agree with pmg.  The code you posted doesn't seem to match the output you posted.  Please double-check that this is the correct code.

Comment: I have since fixed this bug, good spot as it caused my app to crash when it was executed, however it was not the cause of my main problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 for (loop = 0;loop< number_of_samples;loop++){
                /* ... */
                if(fprintf(stream,"Sample %d, %s",loop, tagname) < 0){
                /* ... */
                    if(fprintf(stream,"%s%8.7f, %s, Type:Float\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.Float,szQuality) < 0){
                    /* ... */
                    if(fprintf(stream,"%s%s, %s, Type:String\n",temp,pSamples[loop].Value.String,szQuality) <0){
                    /* ... */
        if(fprintf(stream, "Number of samples: %d\n",number_of_samples) < 0){
        /* ... */
```

Where's the "Type:" output? Are you looking at the right source file?

Comment: Sorry that output was of a previous run minus the type and sample number, the results however are identical with those in there.